# HTML <SELECT> on selected value the other module will be null

Tags: php, html

I need help with this: 
**HTML**

```
  <select class="nesty-input" style="max-width: 100%" name="what_about">
  <option selected disabled hidden><?php echo $what_about[1]; ?></option>
  <option value="0|-">-</option>
  <option value="1|one">one</option>
  <option value="2|two">two</option>
  <option value="3|three">three</option>
  </select>

  <select class="nesty-input" style="max-width: 100%" name="im">
  <option selected disabled hidden><?php echo $im[1]; ?></option>
  <option value="0|-">-</option>
  <option value="1|one">one</option>
  <option value="2|two">two</option>
  <option value="3|three">three</option>
  </select>
```

**PHP**

```
   $what_about = explode('|', $_POST['what_about']); 
   $im = explode('|', $_POST['im']);
```

So, what basically does this script: on page reload prints the value (0=id, 1=text), this because I wanted to do that in the database will be archived the id of the selected item, the problem is that when I select a value and I reload the page it still remains, but when I select the new one the value of the old is null.
Also known as: `Warning: Undefined offset: 1`.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the behavior where the value "remains" on a page refresh?

Comment: No, when I refresh the page and for example I select the first <option> the second will be null, I don't know why of this error.

Comment: Maybe selected attribute is making a default selection in a option width no value defined.

Comment: I was thinking about it too, what do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 0):

You default selected element has no vlaue. So then you you submit it you get default values of `$what_about` and `$im equals ['']`. And somewhere in your code later you are calling for  `$what_about[1]` or  `$im[1]`

I would recommend you to check if `count($what_about) == 2` before you call for `$what_about[1]` and if `count($im) == 2` before you call for `$im[1]`

or set the value for default select option

```
   <option selected disabled hidden value='|'><?php echo $im[1]; ?></option>
```